# Errors on setSource options

Tags: just-audio

Following is my code to load audio (for both iOS and Android) using just_audio. Using most of the code from the just_audio example.

```
Future<void> setAudio() async {
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(const AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());

    // Listen to errors during playback.
    _player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
      print('JustPlayerAudio :: Loading Audio...${event.processingState}');
    }, onDone: () {
      print('JustPlayerAudio :: Loading Completed...');
    }, onError: (Object e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      print('JustAudioPlayer :: Stream error occurred: $e');
    });

    // Try to load audio from a source and catch any errors.
    try {
      if (widget.asset != null) {
        print('JustAudioPlayer :: setAudio : Asset being loaded...');
        await _player
            .setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.file(widget.asset!.path)));
      } else {
        print('JustAudioPlayer :: setAudio : Url being loaded...');
        await _player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(widget.url!)));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading audio source: $e");
    }
  }
```

On iOS, first time I load a music file from device, it produces the following log

[image]

It looks like the audio was not loaded, but when I click the play button, the file plays and the log continues as below:

[image]

Now, if I attempt to repeat the loading of another file, the below happens:

[image]

And this time, the Audio play control goes into loading (CircularProgressIndicator) state. If I hot reload, the old songs plays.

The concerns I have is, loading errors are being thrown in two different places for two different attempts. How to avoid this "Cannot Open" error when its not really an error. And how to update player state when Stream error occurs.

Comment: Are you writing data to that file path to prepare its contents before passing it into just_audio? If so, you need to make sure the data is fully written and synced to the filesystem before passing it into just_audio otherwise just_audio will see a partially written audio file and that will be interpreted as an invalid audio file.

Comment: Not writing data. Its a pre-existing file in the iPhone music app. And it gets picked and plays the entire audio, so not a permission or writing issue. Using file_picker to pick the files. Is there an expectation on the file path ? I believe the path starts `/private/..`.

Comment: iOS has rules about file name extensions, and won't be able to decode an audio file unless the extension is correct.

Comment: I notice that irrespective of whatever extension types I upload to the device, the audio picked has a `.m4a` extension in the app. Could this be the issue ?

Comment: Maybe, it's something you can experiment with. Let me know if it works and I can write up a formal answer.